# SQLite3: programatically determine whether a column is sorted in ascending or descending order

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing

Suppose I have an index on a table in SQLite3:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (id integer primary key, firstName varchar(20), lastName varchar(20), address varchar(200));
CREATE INDEX IX_Person ON Person (lastName ASC, firstName ASC);
```

I can discover which columns are in the index like this:

```
sqlite> pragma index_info('ix_person');
0|2|lastName
1|1|firstName
```

But this does not tell me whether the columns sorted are in ascending or descending order.

Is there a way to determine this programatically without re-parsing the `CREATE INDEX` statement?

Comment: I'm struggling to think of a siutation where this would matter - do you have a use case?

Comment: @Mike Woodhouse, I want to do this in a schema management tool, not in the main application.  I am creating groups of related tables where an index in one table must be replicated in another (with additional columns.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"without re-parsing the CREATE INDEX statement" it's really difficult; but getting the CREATE INDEX sql code from the `sqlite_master` table and doing lightweight parsing seems reasonably easy.

Since you can get the column names from the `PRAGMA` you have already identified, all you need to do is *tokenize* that SQL and check token(s) immediately-following (in the CREATE INDEX sql code) the token that's the column name.

There will be a possible `COLLATE somecollation` (which you should probably also record, since what collation is in use *is* pretty important after all), and, possibly after those two optional tokens, the very next one will be ASC, DESC, or something else (meaning no order is specified in the SQL).

((BTW, you no doubt also want the info on whether the index is unique -- that one you can get either by parsing, or, probably better, with "PRAGMA index_list" on the table, which I imagine you're already doing anyway to get the index names)).

I don't think you should make assumptions about whether index files take ordering into account (the newer "descending file" format) or not (the legacy format) -- that depends on [`PRAGMA legacy_file_format`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_legacy_file_format) ...and querying it tells you what will happen for new databases, not what's happening for the current DB. So, faithfully recording the ordering information from the schema seems a much more robust strategy to me.

Comment: I had not considered collation.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that the sort-order has conceptually anything to do with indices. AFAIK it is part of ANSI-SQL, but is mostly ignored by most RDBMSs (like Oracle).

This seems to be the case for older versions of SQLite as well (from the SQLite documentation):

> Each column name can be followed by one of the "ASC" or "DESC" keywords to indicate sort order. The sort order may or may not be ignored depending on the database file format. The "legacy" file format ignores index sort order.

At least according to the documentation, the index-info pragma does not help you in determining the sort order within the index. So it looks as if you are out of luck ...

Comment: It seems like it would make a big difference for multi-column indexes.

Comment: If it will definitely be ignored then always treating it as ASC would be an acceptable solution.

Comment: For multi-column indexes the order of the columns within the index would be important, but I can't see the sort order be of much effect. I think of an index like a well-balanced tree, so the difference between asc and desc wold be wether to "turn" left or right, but it shoud not affect the depth of the tree.