# How do I check the sorting on a index column?

Tags: sqlite, indexing

I can find the list of indexes for a table by using the following:

```
PRAGMA index_list(myTable);
```

From the results of this, I can get details about the columns within an index with the following:

```
PRAGMA index_info(myIndex);
```

But I cannot seem to find a way to tell the columns sort order. Is there another pragma that I have overlooked that can let me do this?

Note: I know that I can select from `SQLITE_MASTER` and parse the sort order out of the create statement, but I would prefer to stay out of parsing if possible. However if this is the only solution, then it will have to work.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1549444/623041).

Comment: At least if you go with parsing, the syntax is simple and well-defined: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html .  A regex to capture the column name(s) and asc/desc will be simple to build.  I can help with that if useful.

Comment: A regex would be great, but would it be possible considering the needs for recursion (multiple columns), optional collation and sort orders, plus column names may or may not be escaped with square brackets? (I'm not very good at regexes and this one seems much more complex than any I have ever written). It seems that it may be much easier to do string parsing).

Answer (score 0):

After a quick grep through the 3.7.13 source code, I don't believe the sort order is exposed by any of the pragmas. The only references to KeyInfo::aSortOrder that I can find are either in the CREATE INDEX code, or in actual database operations like querying or comparing indices with one another.

It doesn't look like it would be a lot of work to add it to the index_info pragma, if doing a custom build of SQLite is an option for you.